# Repeatedly show prompt when input is not correct

Tags: javascript

I have here a prompt which enables the user to input his/her password. My problem is I want it to prompt whenever the user input is not equal to the password set. Here's my code.

```
    var padmin="hello";
    function myFunction(){
        var x= prompt("Input password for security purposes");
        if(x==padmin){
            return true;
        }else{
           return false;
        }
    }

    if(self.myFunction() == true){
        alert("password correct!");                
    }else{
        self.myFunction();
    }
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is exits after 2 propmts is because you are using `if...else`. To loop in this manner, you should use recursion.

#### Logic:

- Break you code in 3 parts:

  1. Accept input and validate equality
  2. Check for validity from above function and process termination condition.
  3. Business logic (*alert in this case*) on success.
- Now you just have to loop over #2.

Also, `x == padmin` will return boolean. So if you do not have any processing, just use `return x === padmin`

Also note that any variable defined outside any function becomes part of global scope and it is **bad practice** to bleed on global scope. Move this variable inside a function where it is required.

```js
function acceptPassword() {
  var padmin = "hello";
  var x = prompt("Input password for security purposes");
  return x === padmin;
}

function validate() {
  return acceptPassword() || validate();
}

function notify() {
  if (validate()) {
    alert("password is correct")
  }
}

notify();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use with in `myFunction` .Add the if and else statement  with in `myFunction` they will prompt until password match

```js
var padmin = "hello";

function myFunction() {
  var x = prompt("Input password for security purposes");
  if (x == padmin) {
   alert("password correct!");
  } else {
 myFunction();
  }
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

Either use a infinite loop, that breaks on correct password.

```
var isPasswordCorrect = false;
var password = ''; 
while(!isPasswordCorrect){
   password = prompt(' Input password for security purposed '); 
   isPasswordCorrect = validatePassword(password);
   if(isPasswordCorrect)
       alert('password correct!');
}

function validatePassword (password){
   /*validation logic here, return true if password is correct,
     else return false 
   */
}
```

Another way is to simply do a recursive call:

```
function validatePassword(){
  var password = password = prompt(' Input password for security purposed ');

  var isPasswordCorrect;/*check password and store here*/
  if( isPasswordCorrect){
    return true;
  }else{
    return validatePassword();
  }

}
```